# How to remove Enter Password from Touch id 'try again' Alert view?

Tags: ios, touch-id

I could remove the Enter form Touch id, the code is below, but how when the authenticate fails, the 'try again' dialog show up with the Enter Password, I don't know how to remove it.

```
//...
LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];

// Hide "Enter Password" button

context.localizedFallbackTitle = @"";
```

Answer (score 2):

By design you can't remove it, it is part of the security. This prevents endless Touch ID attempts.

In general security adds extra steps and that is more hassle to the user, it is unfortunate but true. Example: a door lock adds difficulty, that is a tradeoff between ease of use and security. Tough ID allows easier security in many instances but has weaknesses and the fall back to passcode/password entry after failures is necessary to maintain the security at a higher level.

Comment: thank you,I know what you mean,but if I'd like to remove it by force,what should I do? any suggestion?

Comment: You want to weaken the security, why would Apple allow that? Why would that be good for the user? It wouldn't.

Comment: It's reasonable to assume that passcode is also a weakness. Apple used to implement a log pause with security notifications